# Return true of false if key is true

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display events only if the current user is a guest which I check using `checkGuest(event.$key)`

```
<md-card class="home-card" *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a *ngIf="checkGuest(event.$key)" [routerLink]="['event', event.$key]">
        <img class="event-home-img" src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
        <p class="home-page-title">{{ event.name }}</p>
        <p class="home-page-venue">{{venueName}}</p>
    </a>
</md-card>
```

Firebase list `eventsGuestsLookup` looks like this:

```
{
  "uid1" : {
    "-Ktm57w59Q_2c48r6ntx" : true,
  },
  "uid2" : {
    "-KtmbLqT0U005Ndelw3S" : true,
    "-KtmcLr44X0ho1NZP_h_" : true,
    "-KtmdP2BKzhwezxa-Lbl" : true,
    "-KtoGScCD7Zq4N3KkQQG" : true
  }
}
```

`this.uid` is `uid2` and `eventKey` is `-Ktm57w59Q_2c48r6ntx` an event key which isn't even in the `uid2` list. I expect it to `this.hello` to return false but the only event in the database is being displayed for a user `uid2` ... What am I doing wrong?

```
checkGuest(eventKey: string): Observable<Boolean> {

    const event = this.db.object(`eventsGuestsLookup/${this.uid}/${eventKey}`);

    return event.map(e => this.hello(e));
  }

  hello(e): Boolean {
    if (e) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: If I subscribe to event i get this `{$value: null, $key: "-Ktm57w59Q_2c48r6ntx", $exists: ƒ}`

Comment: curious, what js syntax is that that allows to pass arguments types and return types? is that angular?

Comment: instead of map try using flatMap just to get one response or switchMap to get the latest

Comment: yes. it is Angular

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing **'map'** on an object?

If you want to map through the results you should use **db.list**.

[Angular firebase](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md)

Comment: Your database should return something like this :- [ { '-Ktm57w59Q_2c48r6ntx': {value: true} } ] and not '-Ktm57w59Q_2c48r6ntx': true

Comment: It did that when I subscribed to `event` But I console.loged and it blocked my browser. If I do `console.log(e)` I don't get anything. I can't `return event.subscribe ... `

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Boolean` object instead of a `boolean` primitive. Could that be the issue?

**EDIT/UPDATE (Sept 13, 2017):**

I haven't worked with `angularfire` at all, but from your code it looks like your `ngIf` predicate function `checkGuest()`, is returning a `FirebaseObjectObservable<boolean>` which I think might be `truthy`-always regardless of its `boolean` value (as it is wrapped as an observable).

I think if you change your `checkGuest()` method to this,

```
checkGuest(eventKey: string): boolean {
 return this.db.object(`eventsGuestsLookup/${this.uid}/${eventKey}`)
  .subscribe((e) => this.hello(e.$value));
}
```

it might work. Give it try if you are still looking for an answer.

Comment: Changed to `boolean` .. event still there